# Where I can make chocolates in Switzerland

Tags: food-and-drink, switzerland, study

I'm going with my wife to Europe from 27/March until 15/April and we are looking for some good place where we will can make the true/traditional Swiss Chocolate.

Some course or workshop for a short period, there's something like that in some city of Switzerland?

I'm looking for local courses, more like "typical/traditional" and not a tourist course like "Lindt factory" offers.

Example of answers that I'm expecting and why I did not just googled it:

- I know an small factory on a small city where you can learn how to do a incredible Swiss traditional chocolate.
- I know a good chef who made some courses here in my city.
- Zurich is not a good city for this, try to look at 'another city'

Comment: @MaxFerreira, are you referring to a recreational course or a course that confers a license of some sort?

Comment: Both work for me. It's just because my wife want to starts make chocolat here in Brazil and we really loves the Swiss chocolates, so she wants to understand a little bit more about how's that are created.

Comment: @MaxFerreira, I used to work at a company with a modest confectionery operation in Zug (South of Zurich). And it's an ordeal even for a visiting employee to get inside and the floor itself is a controlled zone. But on more practical terms, is your wife fluent enough in German?

Comment: I once asked a question about learning chocolate from the farm on up if you're interested: [Can I participate in the farming/harvesting of chocolate/cacao as a tourist anywhere in the world?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13368)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me start by saying that chocolate making is not something that is a very common past time even for us Swiss people (at least not if you are talking making chocolate from scratch). Nevertheless I think you have several options here. Those will also mostly depend on whether your wife is fluent either in French or German:

**Cooking courses for local people**

This would definitely be the cheapest option with two big caveats: It's probably going to be taught in one of the national languages and it might not be at the level you are wishing for. If you are however interested in this, you can have a look at the Migros Club Schools which are located everywhere throughout the country. You can have a look under their [culinary section](http://www.klubschule.ch/Angebote/Kultur-Kreativitaet/Kochen-und-Genuss) by searching for a term like "Schokolade" or "chocolat" depending on your language preference. I could find quite a couple of courses.

**Cooking seminars offered as activity for groups**

This option is usually offered for company outings. While this includes the touristy ones such as [Cailler](http://cailler.ch/en/maison-cailler/ateliers-du-chocolat/) [etc](http://www.maestrani.ch/lang-en/fuehrungen-a-events/giesskurs.html), there seems to be some smaller confectionery shops or factories which offer such courses (Have a look at [this](http://www.suteria.ch/en/event/), [this](http://maisontruffe.ch/kurse-events/) or [this](http://www.islertorten.ch/content/e8/index_ger.html)). While this is mainly for groups, it should be possible to book the event for just your wife if you are willing to pay. Again, they might only speak German, but you can always email them and ask them if they have someone who can teach you in English.

**Courses for gastronomic professionals**

There is of course also a whole range of courses directly aimed at cooking professionals. I am not one of those, so I cannot vouch for the quality of such offers. There seems to be a [chocolate academy](http://www.chocolate-academy.com/ch/de/) which incidentally also offers English courses in a range of countries and even courses in Brazil. The courses in Switzerland seem to be either in German or French (you can switch language and country with the button on the upper right corner). There is also a [Chocolatier School](http://www.ecolechocolat.com/en/swiss_chocolate.html). On the high end there is even a one-year [Certificate in Swiss Pastry and Chocolate Arts](http://www.culinaryartsswitzerland.com/en/simple/programs/undergraduate-program/specialisation-in-swiss-pastry-chef-1861) including a paid internship, however the fees are very high (40k CHF).

Now you might wonder how do Swiss people who do this for a living get to learn their trade. The most common way is to do an [apprenticeship](http://www.about.ch/education/index.html) at a confectionery shop or bakery. This is either a [2-year](http://www.berufsberatung.ch/dyn/1203.aspx?data=activity&id=7969&id_zihlmann=2) or a [3-year](http://www.berufsberatung.ch/dyn/1203.aspx?data=activity&id=2956&id_zihlmann=2) vocational education including both on the job training and school training. This is free and is even paid (at a rather minimal salary). While this is usually done after secondary school, this is also accessible to adults.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a new answer on 14 Feb 2015 to cite an article in the *New York Times* which was published on 11 Feb 2015...

Failing the availability of a course...

The New York Times published an article T[he Kitchen-Counter Chocolatiers](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/11/dining/homemade-chocolate-from-bean-to-bar.html?src=twr&smid=tw-nytimes&_r=0#) along with a brilliant photo essay [Chocolate Making at Home](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/11/dining/homemade-chocolate-from-bean-to-bar.html?src=twr&smid=tw-nytimes&_r=0#slideshow/100000003498025/100000003498027) which provides some tips you may find helpful in connecting with small Swiss chocolatiers.

More interestingly, the article refers to a blog called [The Ultimate Chocolate Blog](http://ultimatechocolateblog.blogspot.ca/2014/03/bean-to-bar-craft-chocolate-makers-in.html) which lists small family-based chocolatiers based in the United States and Canada.  You might try contacting the blogger to see if they can refer you to a similar operation in Switzerland.  As a matter of convenience, you can post an enquiry on the [blogger's Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Ultimate-Chocolate-Blog-wwwultimatechocolateblogblogspotcom/282767295087173?sk=wall).